# What is "leave with pre-trained" in learning to listening context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, writing

Paragraph taken from [The Key to Learning Pronunciation](https://fluent-forever.com/learning-pronunciation/#comment-54029), written by Fluent Forever. It discusses about a method to improve the ability of listening for language learners: learning with feedback. The limit of this method is 80% accuracy.

> What if we had this tool in every language? What if we could start out by taking a few audio tests with feedback and **leave with pre-trained**, 80% accuracy ears, even before we began to learn the rest of our language?

If the ears are trained from 50% accuracy to 80% accuracy, why is it called *pre-trained*? And since we use those ears to learn the rest of the language, why does the author use *leave*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the order of actions this way. Basically *leave* indicates moving on to the next action. So:

First:

> taking a few audio tests with feedback (the training)

Second:

> **leave** (from wherever you went 'theoretically' for those tests) with 80% accuracy ears

Third:

> began to learn the rest of our language (with the 80% accuracy ears we now have). It is **pre-trained** because we got this ability in the first step above.

To understand *leave* better, you could replace "a few audio tests with feedback" with "a training class" (in a classroom environment).

> What if we could start out by taking **a training class**, and leave **(the class)** with pre-trained, 80% accuracy ears...

The definition used for [***leave***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/leave) would be:

> 8) to go away from   ⇒ *"to leave the house"*

Comment: I'm still confused in the meaning of *leave*. If you replace it with another word, which one will you use?

Comment: Please check my edits.